# javafx Intellij IDEA index user control

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

When im use `fx:controller` in fxml file all works ok, but im can't use `fx:controller` if it User Control (`fx:root` top tag). 
Because of this, Intellij stops indexing the file, and in the controller file I get a warning because the variable is not assigned.

```
<fx:root prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="710.0" type="VBox" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171"
         xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <FlowPane fx:id="flow" columnHalignment="CENTER" hgap="25.0" vgap="25.0"/>
</fx:root>
```

[image: Intellij idea screen]
How can I specify a controller file for indexing without using `fx:controller`?

Comment: Hi, can you please provide the sample project or the full code of controller and fxml file where you experience the issue. Thanks

Comment: @OlgaKlisho There is an element code in the question. FXML and JAVA files are named the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im found solution, first I still put `fx:controller` attribute, but instead

```
public CustomControl() {
    try {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("CustomControl.fxml"));
        loader.setRoot(this);
        loader.setController(this);
        loader.load();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Im use

```
public CustomControl() {
    try {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("CustomControl.fxml"));
        loader.setRoot(this);
        loader.setControllerFactory(theClass -> this);
        loader.load();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Im just replace `FXMLLoader#setController` with `FXMLLoader#setControllerFactory` and now loader successfully loads my custom control